# Wildcard Loader function called multiple times (_load)

Tags: 7, nodes, routes

I have a loader function which is called excessively whenever the user accesses the page. Naturally, I only need it to run once per page request, instead, it is called multiple times. Earlier the _load() ran only twice with MENU_CALLBACK, then I tested it with the default MENU_NORMAL_ITEM and it increased to four. Although I've changed it back, and cleared my cache, it still runs four times now, and I only want it to run once.

My question is, why is my loader function being called multiple times? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
$items['daycare/%isValid/home'] = array(
    'title' => 'Daycare Admin Home',
    'page callback' => 'daycares_home_page',
    'load arguments' => array(0),//Passes 1st part of url 'daycare' as 2nd arg
    'page arguments' => array(0),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);

function isValid_load($pageID, $pageType){
    /*Do stuff to validate wildcard part of URL. Will throw 404/403 if invalid*/
    return $pageId;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[There's an issue for this](http://drupal.org/node/1471554). It looks like you have to implement caching in your loader.

I was curious and tried it out on `admin/structure/types/manage/%node_type`. I grepped for `node_type_load` and nothing seemed to be calling it directly, so I put a `ddebug_backtrace()` in the load function. I got 13 traces when visiting that path! 10 of these came from menu_local_tasks() which loops through the local tasks and calls `_menu_translate()` which calls `_menu_load_objects()` for each router item. The other two extra calls came via `menu_set_active_trail()` which also called `_menu_translate()`. So I guess it depends on your menu structure how many times a loader might be called. As far as I can tell the object's loaded only to check whether or not it can be (access is denied if it can't). I guess this just reinforces [Damien's comment about implementing static caching in your loader](http://drupal.org/node/1471554#comment-5700380).

Comment: I"m trying the caching method right now, I'll post again when I get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually implement static yourself:

```
function isValid_load($pageID, $pageType){
    static $page;
    if (!isset($page)) {
      // Do expensive stuff here. If you set $page to FALSE it will cause a
      // 404 error when someone tries to call the page.
    }
    return $page; 
}
```

This way your expensive stuff will only run once per pageload.